# Push button when LED comes on

Tags: electric-vehicle, led, dashboard

I have a button in my Electric car, with a small LED in it.
By default when I turn on the car, the LED in the button lights up. Pushing the button turns the LED and the Fake engine noise OFF.
The button is controlling a Fake engine sound generated at low speed. But I do not want this functionality and now I manually have to push the button everytime. There is no way to change the default state.

What I would like is that when the LED turns ON, it should simulate that I push the button to turn it off. Preferably with a small delay to prevent multiple button presses. And I also imagine that it could be self powered by the current going to the LED.

So I was wondering if anyone could help me design a small circuit or point me to a ready solution?

I tried to search but most I found includes microcontrollers, and I want the circuit to be as small and simple as possible as I want it to be near the button, and not needing external power.

Comment: Can you edit your question to explain why you haven't unplugged the switch? What is this mystery button's intended function?

Comment: Without a circuit schema, it's impossible to help you.

Comment: I'd think that the function that is activated on engine start-up might be important. What function is it? Why do you not want it?

Comment: Added some more details.

Comment: Is the "fake" engine noise audible outside the vehicle? I have heard that since electric cars are so quiet that pedestrians are at risk from possibly walking in front of unseen (and unheard) electric vehicles. if so, this may be a safety feature that you do not want to bypass.

Comment: I avoided adding the reason for the button to avoid this turning into a political discusion. I live in Sweden and for now there is no rule that the car has to have the noise.

Comment: Disconnect the speaker.

Comment: @RDrast great idea, unless it's played through the car's stereo system which is common.

Comment: Why don't you rig the button up to a really big stereo, that way pedestrians can hear you coming, or re-program the speaker to constantly play "Born to be Wild!"

Answer (score 1):

It may require some experimentation to get it right, but perhaps a small reed relay will do what you want. Connect the coil in series with the LED, and connect the contacts in parallel with the switch.

Comment: That is a good idea, I will try to get hold of one. Could I add a few components to get a small delay before it switches?

Comment: As @matsk already said, it's impossible to be more specific without seeing the details of the car's wiring (schematic diagram).

Comment: You could have the small delay using an Arduino. It costs some amount of money, but then again it will be much easier to create a delay using Arduino when compared to designing your own circuit.